# Solve $\sin(z) = \frac{3+i}{4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

What i did so far was this:

$$\sin(z)=\frac{3+i}{4}\Rightarrow\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=\frac{3+i}{4}\Rightarrow e^{2iz}-1=\left(\frac{-1+3i}{2}\right)e^{iz}$$

setting $u=e^{iz}$ we'll have

$$u^2+\left(\frac{1-3i}{2}\right)u-1=0$$

completing squares

$$\left(u+\frac{1-3i}{4}\right)^2=\frac{3}{8}(1+i)$$

seting $w=u + \frac{1-3i}{4}$

$$w^2=\frac{3}{8}(1+i)$$

solving

$$w=\pm2^{\frac{-5}{4}}\sqrt{3}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)\right)$$

now i just have to substitute this in $w=u + \frac{1-3i}{4}$ and then in $u=e^{iz}$, but the solution looks really big and really different from the answer i got from [here](https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/en/solve-problem/%60sin%20z%20=%20%60frac%20%7B%203%20%7D%20%7B%204%20%7D%20+%20%60frac%20%7B%20i%20%7D%20%7B%204%20%7D). So what did i do wrong? Or, if i didn't do anything wrong, can i simplify somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a mistake while completing the square; it should be$$\left(u+\frac{1-3i}4\right)^2=\frac12-\frac38i=\left(\frac34-\frac14i\right)^2.$$So, you get that$$u+\frac{1-3i}4=\pm\left(\frac34-\frac14i\right),$$and that therefore$$u=-1+i=e^{\log\sqrt2+\frac{3\pi}4i}\quad\text{or}\quad u=\frac12+\frac12i=e^{-\log\sqrt2+\frac\pi4i}.\quad$$